# Can't add a KML in Android Emulator

Tags: android, linux, emulation, kml, archlinux

I can't add my KML to my Android Emulator, it doesn't appear in the folder (it's in desktop)

[image: 1]

I'm using Arch Linux, I already rebooted the pc, and rebooted the Emulator, can anyone help me?

Comment: need to repllace error description here

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to find a solution for your problem, because of lack of information.

Most likely your file in your Desktop folder doesn't end with `*.gpx` or `.kml`.

Open a terminal or just use the shortcut `ALT` + `F2` and then type:

```bash
move ~/Escritorio/Indicaciones* ~/Escritorio/Indicaciones.kml
```

If it doesn't work, open a terminal and type:

```
ls -la ~/Escritorio/
file ~/Escritorio/In*
ls -la ~/Desktop/
```

The char `~` stands for your home path.

If you have done, please post the output in your question.